# How can we derive the entities related to verb in a sentence using Natural Language Processing techniques?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

If we are given text and we need to extract the noun phrases which are dominated by the verb in each sentence of that text. How can we figure out such entities?

Comment: You might be looking for a dependency parser.
https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/nndep.html

Comment: Thank you for the guidance.